# Android SearchView not positioning correctly

Tags: android, listview

I downloaded some sample code here https://trinitytuts.com/get-contact-list-and-show-in-custom-listview-android/ which searches and lists contacts in my phone. The resulting app builds and loads well. I believe it uses the Android search widget as at the top of my mainactivity I have :

```
import android.widget.SearchView
```

(However I do not have a searachable.xml file which I have seen in some sources 
is a feature of this Search Widget)

According to Google, I believe the searchview widget can be
positioned anywhere in the activity (I don't want it at the top
of the activity, I want it at the bottom):
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#TheBasics

According to Google in the link above the the search dialogue always appears at the top of an activity, however I am lead to believe the widget can be positioned in different places.

But when I try to change the position of the Searchview in my activity, it doesn't display.

For example, this works fine in my activity_main xml, the searchview is at the top of the page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SearchView

        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:queryHint="howdy"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SearchView>

    <ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But in this case the SearchView isn't visible at all. Any ideas how I can place my search widget at the bottom?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"></ListView>

    <SearchView

        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:queryHint="howdy"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SearchView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try placing your search view above the list view and put this inside the search view widget `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and let me know if that works or not

Comment: Thanks, but had no effect at all. Searchview is still at the top. Isn't android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" a Relative layout property (mine is linearlayout)?

Comment: No. I have a linear layout in my project and when I use the same thing with center it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list view is hiding SearchView..

You can do following to see its going at the end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.codepath.mytestapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:queryHint="howdy"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Help me understand. How is putting the list view in a linear layout going to change the situation? Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't know how that fixed it - can't understand how my listview was hiding the searchview, guess I'll have to study it - but it's done. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain, what is the difference between tags like <ListView></ListView> and <ListView> with just />

Comment: Your list is taking complete height, if you restrict height then you can see your serchView at the end. Just to understand put 100dp as height on ListView

Comment: Also <ListView></ListView> and <ListView/> both are same. If there is no content then its recommended to use <ListView/>. It also reduce LOC

Comment: Oh ok, I thought wrap_content would have left room for other views on the page.

Comment: @Shyam Thanks Shyam!